# Removing all occurences of all charactesr from second string in first string

Tags: c, linux, unix, system

I have a small problem.
I have a function that takes in two parameters (two strings). For example:
String1 = "hello"
String2 = "leo"
I need to remove all characters from String2 in String1. In this case, my final result should be: "h". I need to incorporate pointers when doing this! I've got this code so far, but it's only remove "e" from "hello". I don't know why it's not working. If someone has a better or efficient way of doing this, please help!

```
void rmstr(char str1[], char str2[])
{

//Pointers to traverse two strings
char *p_str1 = &str1[0];
char *p_skip;
int length = (int)strlen(str2); 
int i;

while(*p_str1 != '\0')
{
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        if(*p_str1 == str2[i])
        {
            for(p_skip = p_str1; *p_skip == str2[i]; ++p_skip);
            memcpy(p_str1, p_skip, &str1[strlen(str1)+1] - p_skip);
        }

        if(*p_str1 != '\0')
        {
            ++p_str1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are advancing the `p_str1` pointer inside the `for` loop that advances through `str2`. It should be outside of that loop.

Comment: Have you even thought about this? Your code rather obviously only looks for characters at the same offset in both strings, which clearly won't solve the task. And your code would be clearer if you gave the strings names that have something to do with what role the play ... the second string is just an unordered collection of chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* rmstr(char *str1, char *str2, char *ans) {
    char *p1 = str1;
    char *p2 = str2;
    char *res = ans;

    while (*p1 != '\0') {
        p2 = str2;
        while (*p2 != '\0') {
            if (*p1 == *p2)    // A character in str1 is found inside str2
                break;
            p2++;
        }
        if (*p2 == '\0') {   // No match found
            *ans = *p1;
            ans++;
        }
        p1++;
    }
    *ans = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

Testing code:

```
int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "elo";
    char ans[10];

    printf(rmstr(str1, str2, ans));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I often think my code is self-explanatory. And more often than not, I'm wrong. You may want to describe what is different and *why*.

Comment: Thank you very much! The only thing is, I'm suppose to use pointers to traverse through the strings... Thus, although this program works, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer has less variables and maybe easier to read.

```
    #include "stdio.h"

    /* check if c belongs to the second str */
    int char_belong_to_str(char c, char *str)
    {
        while(*str)
            if (c == *str++)
                    return 1;

        return 0;
    }

    void rmstr(char str1[], char str2[])
    {
        int result_len = 0;   /* saves the result str len*/
        char * p_new = str1;

        while (*str1)
        {
            char c = *str1;
            if (!char_belong_to_str(c, str2)) /* if not found in str2, save it*/
            {
                *(p_new + result_len) = c;
                ++result_len;
            }
            ++str1;
        }
        *(p_new+result_len) = '\0';

        printf("%s \n", p_new);
    }

    int main()
    {
        char  p1[] = "hello";
        char  p2[] = "elo";

        rmstr(p1, p2);
        return 0;
    }
```